# Preset Webview in android

Tags: android, xml, webview, hybrid-mobile-app

I know how to set a url for a webview in android. However, I am looking for a solution to hard code it in the xml itself. Probably specify a custom attribute in the xml itslef like this:

```
 <WebView android:id="@string/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:hard_coded_url="http://localhost" />
```

This is the exact use case:

I have a web based CMS that allows users to create mixed content containing text, audio, images and video. The content will be consumed on the android app. To support mixed content I have decided to follow the following strategy:

**-->** Content is created using wysiwyg editor

**->** Parse through and convert it into a fragment XML for android

**->** Each piece of content is then an xml containing text views and web views

**->** Transfer these XML files over the network when user requests content

The reason for this approach is that it creates an atomic unit for each piece of content and I don't have to download the image, audio or video resources to the user's device. Alternative solutions will also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I am looking for a solution to hard code it in the xml itself

That is not possible, except perhaps by creating your own subclass of `WebView` that offers this via a custom attribute.

> Transfer these XML files over the network when user requests content

Since `LayoutInflater` will not support this (it only works with layout resources), you will need to create your own "inflater" from scratch. If you want that inflater to handle `android:hard_coded_url`, you are welcome to do so.

Comment: Thanks! I am considering doing just that. Do you foresee any obvious caveats with this approach?

Comment: Okay, wait can't be done. The second bit seems out of bounds. Considering having hidden placeholders in existing xml instead.